# React Native: Cannot map over state array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to figure out how I can map over an array of objects which is stored in my state via an api call.

**My state object**:

```
state = {
    isLoading: false,
    event: []
};
```

**My render function**:

```
{this.state.event.musicStyle.map((style, index) => {
    return <Text>{style}</Text>;
})}
```

**My API Response**:
[image]

**console log of this.state.event**:
 [image]

**Error Message**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property of 'map' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue is because the first time it render, the value of `this.state.event` is still empty (not exactly empty because you set to be an empty array at first) so accessing `this.state.event.musicStyle` will give an error. I think you need to change to initialize `event` to be `null`, then check if `event` is `not null` then you can do the `map`.

Comment: this is partially correct but the main problem is that `this.state.event` is an array so `this.state.event.musicStyle` will always be undefined. the way you access indexes of an array in javascript is `<array>[position in array]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.state.event` is an array so `this.state.event.musicStyle` will always be undefined...

What you want is something like

```
componentDidMount() {
  return fetch(callToApi)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({event: result})
}
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.event.map((event) => {
      event.musicStyle.map((style) => {
       return <Text>{style}</Text>;
      })  
    })}
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Maxwell for your reply. I call this.setState in my componentDidMount function, the data is successfully stored in my state. Any idea how can I map over an subarray of my event array?

Comment: @Menelik please check me edited response. You just need to iterate over the musicStyle array for each event :)

Comment: Thanks again Maxwelll to try to help me, really appreciate it. When I use your code I get a new error message: `TypeError:this.state.event is not a function` ;( is there a general design error on my side? As this is a event detail page probably there is no need to declare state.event as an array? There will only be details about one event on this screen.

Comment: sorry I forgot .map :D

Comment: I finally solved it with the linked question of Shubham Khatri. I had to provide a check for undefined. The following code is now working `{this.state.event.musicStyle &&
     this.state.event.musicStyle.map(style => {
      return <Text>style</Text>;
     })}`